# Installing NumPy on Windows 8.1 with Python 2.7.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, numpy, pip

I'm very new to Python and programming world and has been going along with tutorials from newcoder.io [This Here!](http://newcoder.io/dataviz/part-0/)  I have been doing as per the instructions but when I try to install NumPy I get an error.

"
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

---

Command "C:\Users\HP.virtualenvs\DataVizProj\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-lsj5sj\numpy\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).re
.replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-6jei4k-record\instal
cord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\HP.virtualenvs\DataVizProj\includ
te\python2.7" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-lsj5sj\numpy

"

But that's not enough, I tried to install VCForPython27.msi from the given link. But still, gets the same error.

Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend installing the Anaconda distribution of Python. It contains more packages than you can dream of, including numpy of course: http://continuum.io/downloads

The installation is as straightforward as installing the usual Python, no matter what OS you are on.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to download the wheel file which match your Python version here:[unofficial python binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

And then go to the folder where the `.whl` file is present using the command prompt and unpack the wheel file `xxxxx.whl` with:

```
>python -m pip install xxxxx.whl
```

This will install the library in the `Lib\site-packages` folder, you can check it afterwards.

Comment: I sorted out the problem myself, but I'll take care of your solution next time I want to install some other library. Thanks.